# WordPress visual composer not showing design options

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using BeTheme for WordPress with visual composer design options are not shown in WP menu under Visual Composer section.
It should be shown like this http://prnt.sc/e9cc9h

Anybody have the same issue and found a solution?

Comment: Try looking for information on the theme's help forum http://forum.muffingroup.com/betheme/

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned, that was my first port of call Unfortunately it is pretty useless doesn't mention anything and the documentation is versions out of date. It seems like Evato are more interested in creating a cash cow the support terms and licenses these days. yet license paid for the  basic documentation for product remains outdated and  new version sections missing.  Think rock and hard place springs to mind.